# How do I assign a variable to an If statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to assign a variable called 'app_price_formula' to remember that it has to do this if statement:

```
opened_file = open('AppleStore.csv')
from csv import reader
read_file = reader(opened_file)
apps_data = list(read_file)
app_price = 30
app_price_formula = if app_price > 30:
    print('This app is expensive')
```

But I get this error

```
File "<ipython-input-1-da34fd0221c3>", line 7
app_price_formula = if app_price > 30:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: So, you want to set `app_price_formula` to a function?  Or you want it to be the result of `app_price > 30`?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can not assign a control structure `if` to a variable. But there is another `if`: the trinary operator `<value> if <condition> else <alternate value>` can be part of an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app_price_formula = (app_price > 30)
if app_price_formula:
    print('This app is expensive')
```

First statement saves `True` or `False` in your variable. Based on value of variable, the if statement executes.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using a `function` like this:

```
def app_price_forumula(app_price):

    if app_price > 30:

        return print("This app is expensive")
```

Example:

```
app_price_formula(40)
```

Which prints:

```
"This app is expensive"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
app_price = 50
app_price_formula = 'This app is expensive' if app_price > 30 else 'This app is cheap'
print(app_price_formula)
```

[execute image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBxS4.png)